# Issues with "!pip install PyDither" on Google colab

Tags: python, opencv, pip

when i did "!pip install PyDither" on Google colab, I got the following error message. How can I fix it?

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting PyDither
  Downloading PyDither-0.0.1.tar.gz (2.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting numpy==1.19.0 (from PyDither)
  Downloading numpy-1.19.0.zip (7.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.3/7.3 MB 93.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyDither) (4.7.0.72)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of opencv-python to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting opencv-python (from PyDither)
  Downloading opencv_python-4.7.0.68-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (61.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.8/61.8 MB 9.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading opencv_python-4.6.0.66-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.9/60.9 MB 13.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.5/60.5 MB 10.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading opencv_python-4.5.5.62-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.4/60.4 MB 13.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.3/60.3 MB 9.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading opencv_python-4.5.4.58-cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.3/60.3 MB 10.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading opencv-python-4.5.3.56.tar.gz (89.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 89.2/89.2 MB 7.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: this has got nothing to do with google colab. -- submit an issue to the author of that package. https://github.com/Utkarsh-Deshmukh/image-dithering-python

Answer (score -1):

```
!pip install PyDither --no-deps
```